# How to use firebase to sign in with google using firebase-auth:11.0.0

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to set up a Google sign in method in my Android project. First, I've successfully implemented a email sign in method, but I can't get Google's to work.

I've read the documentation provided and followed [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXlidHy-Tb8&t=210s)

I can't even find any propper documentation for firebase-auth:11.0.0. Here are my problems:

```
// Sign in with google
private void googleSignIn() {

    /* The Auth class bellow is not recognized by Android Studio or autocomplete */
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

After that, I try to create a onActivityResult:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        // Same problem with the Auth class and the GoogleSignInResultClass
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        }
    }
}
```

These codes have been grabed from the firebase documentation on [this link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/google-signin?utm_source=studio)
I haven't been able to find anything helpful, this was my last option.

Comment: There's entire Github examples that use the latest versions. https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/auth/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/auth/GoogleSignInActivity.java

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "I can't get Google's to work." , does it throws any error?

Comment: I mean that I got the email method working. I've tested and everything. But I can't resolve these issues when trying to implement google Sign in.

Comment: Post the error or result. It's easy to give solution.

Comment: can you get the user details from ( `GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();` ) account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see this code to sign in with google account  it might help you .

```
/**
 * GOOGLE SIGN IN CODE
 * <p/>
 * This code is mostly boiler plate from
 * https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating
 * and
 * https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/SignInActivity.java
 * <p/>
 * The big picture steps are:
 * 1. User clicks the sign in with Google button
 * 2. An intent is started for sign in.
 * - If the connection fails it is caught in the onConnectionFailed callback
 * - If it finishes, onActivityResult is called with the correct request code.
 * 3. If the sign in was successful, set the mGoogleAccount to the current account and
 * then call get GoogleOAuthTokenAndLogin
 * 4. getGoogleOAuthTokenAndLogin launches an AsyncTask to get an OAuth2 token from Google.
 * 5. Once this token is retrieved it is available to you in the onPostExecute method of
 * the AsyncTask. **This is the token required by Firebase**
 */

/* Sets up the Google Sign In Button : https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton */
private void setupGoogleSignIn() {

    Button signInButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login_with_google);

    signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            onSignInGooglePressed(v);
        }
    });
}
/**
 * Sign in with Google plus when user clicks "Sign in with Google" textView (button)
 */
public void onSignInGooglePressed(View view) {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_GOOGLE_LOGIN);
    mAuthProgressDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    /**
     * An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
     * be available.
     */
    mAuthProgressDialog.dismiss();
    showErrorToast(result.toString());
}


/**
 * This callback is triggered when any startActivityForResult finishes. The requestCode maps to
 * the value passed into startActivityForResult.
 */

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    /* Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...); */
    if (requestCode == RC_GOOGLE_LOGIN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        /* Signed in successfully, get the OAuth token */
        mGoogleAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
        firebaseAuthWithGoogle(mGoogleAccount);

    } else {
        if (result.getStatus().getStatusCode() == GoogleSignInStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_CANCELLED) {
            showErrorToast("The sign in was cancelled. Make sure you're connected to the internet and try again.");
        } else {
            showErrorToast("Error handling the sign in: " + result.getStatus().getStatusMessage());
        }
        mAuthProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}

  /**
 * Gets the GoogleAuthToken and logs in.
 */

private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());
                    //  If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "signInWithCredential", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```